# Dynamic Where Clause over relational tables with LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic, where-clause

I need help for a dynamic where clause **over relational tables (one to many)** in LinqToSql.

User select conditions from page. (there is 4 input that user select the clauses)

***For example CompanyName and CompanyTitle from Customer table and OrderDate and ShipCity From Order table.***

But **user can select one ore many of them from page** interface and dynamic query will be generated at codebehind and select From LinqToSql.

You can give similar type of example from another web pages.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Are you looking for something like this, where you define the "base" query, and then evaluate parameters to determine if a where clause is appropriate?

```
var result = (from x in context.X
              select x);

if(some condition)
{
    result = result.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.companyName == name);
}
if(some other condition)
{
    result = result.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.companyTitle == title);
}

//return result.ToList();
//return result.FirstOrDefault();
//return result.Count(); //etc
```

I noticed in one of your comments you mentioned your tables are not joined by a foreign key?  I'm not sure how you get a one-to-many relationship without some kind of referential integrity or relationship?

Comment: I'm a LINQ novice, but wouldn't that retrieve *all* of the data from the DB and then progressively filter it? Seems to me that for largish amounts of data it would be more efficient to get the DB to do the filtering and return just the data you want.

Comment: No, it only executes the select when you perform something like a ToList(), Count() etc.

Comment: To clarify - the database will return all of the data, and the DB client will filter through the rows. This is distinct from passing in the WHERE clause to the DB and returning the filtered data to the DB client. The above code will do the former, thus possibly sending a *lot* more data from DB to DB client than is strictly necessary.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I just tested this (again) to verify.  The actual SELECT command isn't executed until you perform an action which requires a result like .ToList().  If you don't believe me attach the SQL Profiler and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Check out ScottGu's blog on the [dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). I think it will help.

Here is an example of a query that hits both the customers and orders table:

```
    var query =
    db.Customers.
    Where("City = @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
    OrderBy("CompanyName").
    Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

The query above came from the [C# samples for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx).  Download and look in the \LinqSamples\DynamicQuery folder and you will find more examples.

Comment: I visited also this page. In examples, they select from one table and create dynamic where clause over this.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how dynamic you want it to be - as others already suggested the System.Linq.Dynamic namespace adds some neat functionality for composing queries where entities/members (tables/columns) involved are not known at design time. In this case it sounds like the entities and members involved are already known and you just need to alternate between different fields as you where clause criteria. Here's an example of that:

```
from cust in dc.Customer
join ord in dc.Order on cust.CustomerID equals ord.CustomerID
where (companyName == null || cust.CompanyName == companyName)
  and (companyTitle == null || cust.CompanyTitle == companyTitle)
  and (orderDate == null || ord.OrderDate == orderDate)
  and (shipCity == null || ord.ShipCity == shipCity)
select new {cust, ord}
```

Comment: 1 static SQL would not be good. For one query only ONE query plan will be created. In could, for example, work well, if you provide P1, but not well, if you provide P2 or combination of P1 and P3. 
I had a query which join multiple tables(5+) and optional parameters belong to different tables. One query plan didn't work on SQL 2005

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim The example above will *not* result in a single static SQL query. L2S evaluates the parts that can be evaluated client side and generates a SQL query that only include the parts that need to be evaluated by the database. If e.g. the companyName parameter is null, the company name portion will never make it to the SQL where clause. This is one of the beautiful things in Linq-to-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

RobS supplied what I think is the most attractive solution. However, this is the method I was using but then I realized that it is actually performing the first query in full (Linq-To-SQL) and then the subsequent .Where() clauses are performed with just LINQ. So this is not a viable solution as the entire set of data is enumerated and then filtered out aftwerwards in memory.

Please correct me if I'm wrong - but this is what I've noticed.

Comment: Can you post any example?  In my experience (proven with SQL Profiler) the query is not executed until you preform some sort of operation, such as ToList(), Count() etc.